Can I Use Expo EAS for a React Native Project Not Created with Expo?
I am working on a React Native project that was not created using Expo. I would like to use Expo EAS (Expo Application Services) to build my project, but I am running into some issues. Here are the details:
When I run eas build:configure, I get the following error:
(node:71433) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Cannot find module 'expo/config-plugins'
Require stack:
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/Desktop/valemgo-customer/node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin/plugin/build/withGoogleSignIn.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/Desktop/valemgo-customer/node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin/app.plugin.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/plugin-resolver.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withStaticPlugin.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withPlugins.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/index.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/build/build/android/syncProjectConfiguration.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/build/commands/build/configure.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/module-loader.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/plugin.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/config.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/index.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/command.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/bin/run
    Error: build:configure command failed.

I also tried running eas build and encountered similar issues:
(node:71772) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
✔ Select platform › All
✔ Generated eas.json. Learn more
Loaded "env" configuration for the "production" profile: no environment variables specified. Learn more
Cannot find module 'expo/config-plugins'
Require stack:
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/Desktop/valemgo-customer/node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin/plugin/build/withGoogleSignIn.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/Desktop/valemgo-customer/node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin/app.plugin.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/plugin-resolver.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withStaticPlugin.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withPlugins.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/index.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/build/build/android/syncProjectConfiguration.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/build/build/android/build.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/build/build/runBuildAndSubmit.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/build/commands/build/index.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/module-loader.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/plugin.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/config.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/config/index.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/command.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/salihburakcoskun/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/bin/run
    Error: build command failed.

Questions:

Can I use Expo EAS for a React Native project that was not created with Expo?

If so, what are the necessary steps to properly configure my project to use EAS?

How can I resolve the missing module errors mentioned above?


Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
I have already tried installing expo, expo-cli, and @expo/config-plugins, but the issue persists.
